# Android Kotlin: App flickering when clicking app overview button

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragments

For some reason clicking the App over view button (the button next to the home button and lets you view all apps running) makes my app flicker... What would be the reason?

I am currently using one activity, all other screens are fragments stacked on each other. Could that be the problem?
Also, when clicking on the app over view button, sometimes all the fragments will simply be removed leading me back to my singular main activity...

Comment: That's a couple of questions without much detail. I recommend you separate them in to different questions and include the relevant info (code you think is responsible, etc) and re-post

Comment: The main problem here is that I do not know where the problem is coming from... Any suggestions?

Comment: By stacked on each other, do you mean you literally are drawing a bunch of fragments at once, like they are all in your view hierarchy siultaneously?

Comment: I've seen flaky behaviour from the emulator recently, some of the UI starts glitching or outright disappears. Try closing the emulator and starting it from the AVD Manager with the "Cold Boot" option, get a fresh one going

Comment: @Tenfour04 I have the MainActivity as a base activity. On top of that, I have a bottom navigation view, where users can view the main page fragment and the profile edit fragment. On top of the profile edit fragment, a new edit fragment appears whenever a user wants to edit a field. This is not the complete picture, and there are more fragments here and there all stacked on the single MainActivity.

Comment: @cactustictacs all the other default apps work fine, it is just my app that is showing this behavior

Comment: @Ian the app switcher is part of the system UI, if you're getting flickering when you go into that. As far as I know there's no way for your app to affect that (the thumbnail is just a screenshot the system takes), if you're doing a lot of work in ``onPause`` or something it could stutter. On the other thing, if your app is losing state then you need to make sure you're handling that correctly: https://developer.android.com/guide/fragments/saving-state You can't rely on your app being kept in memory, so it has to be able to restore itself when necessary